# An absolutely convergent series may be rearranged.

Tags: sequences-and-series, absolute-convergence

Any rearrangement of an absolutely convergent sequence $(a_n)$ is another absolutely convergent sequence with the same limit.  Let $(a_{\sigma(n)})$ be the rearranged sequence under the bijection of indices $\sigma$.

My proof attempt.  Let $T_N = \sum_{n=1}^N |a_{\sigma(n)}|$ be the $N$th partial sum of the rearranged absolute series.   Similarly let $S_N$ be the partial sum of the original absolute series.   I know I want to try to prove the absolute sequences Cauchy.  Still working on it.

Comment: So, not much of an attempt, then?

Comment: Hold on, I just thought of something

Comment: Here is the key hint: Given $n$, show that if $N$ is large enough, then all surviving terms in $T_N-S_N$ have index larger than $n$.

Comment: In  think your first two "sequence" in the body of the question must be changed to "series".

Comment: @DonAntonio The OP should rather say "absolutely summable".

Comment: Try solving it yourself. If you do not succeed, look it up in a textbook. If you do not understand the proof there, think about it. If you still do not understand it, ask.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Is that a command or a recommendation? =)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Just me being annoyed, but I take your hint and go to bed now.

Answer (score 7):

You needn't make the $N$s match. You know you can take $N$ large enough so that $$\sum_{k\geqslant N}|a_k|<\varepsilon$$

Now pick $M$ large enough so that all the terms in $T_M$ are some of the terms in $S_N$. Then how large is $$\left|\sum_{k\geqslant 0}a_k-T_M\right|?$$

Comment: I don't know the first part.  Will have to prove it.

Comment: @EnjoysMath Check the definition of "absolutely summable" again!

Comment: Why can we pick M large enough so that all the terms in Tm  are some of the terms in Sn? @PedroTamaroff

Comment: @Waizman $T_M$ is finite, so if you go far enough into $S_N$ you will find all these terms.